# How to select from this field

Tags: sql, presto

Bit of a SQL newbie here.

I have a field from a data table that is in an odd format (pasted below) and not sure how to select individual fields from it. For example I'd like to do a query like:

`select * from table where cf_engineering_required = false`

However, I can't seem to pull out a specific field and its value. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Many thanks!

```
 ['{name=cf_engineering_required',     'value=false}',
  '{name=cf_channel',                  'value=booking.com}',
  '{name=cf_travelnest_booking_id',    'value=none}',
  '{name=cf_finance_type',             'value=none}',
  '{name=cf_raised_by',                'value=none}',
  '{name=cf_owner_id',                 'value=none}',
  '{name=cf_property_id',              'value=none}',
  '{name=cf_cause',                    'value=none}',
  '{name=cf_payout_gbp',               'value=none}',
  '{name=cf_complaint_against',        'value=none}',
  '{name=cf_threatened_legal_action',  'value=false}',
  '{name=cf_customer_id',              'value=none}',
  '{name=cf_verification_flag',        'value=none}',
  '{name=cf_total_verification_score', 'value=none}',
  '{name=cf_initial_email_sent',       'value=false}',
  '{name=cf_reminder_email_sent',      'value=false}',
  '{name=cf_scrutiny_type',            'value=none}',
  '{name=cf_outcome',                  'value=none}',
  '{name=cf_verification_outcome',     'value=none}',
  '{name=cf_booking_types',            'value=guest enquiry}',
  '{name=cf_case_types',               'value=none}'
 ]
```

Comment: This is JSON data  -- you need to use queries that support JSON to access it.

Comment: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html

Comment: @Hogan this is no valid json it is an array of strings

Comment: @nbk -- what do you mean -- according to this it is a valid JSON array.  Why do you say it is not valid?  https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: @Hogan no, it is not json data, if you want to treat it as key-value pairs.

Comment: oh -- it is not valid JSON because it uses single quotes?  so it just some random text format.

Comment: Yeah -- you are screwed OP -- there is no way to query this in the DB you need to download the fields and query them on the client - or refactor your DB to put this data in tables